# HTML conditional brainching (if else)

Tags: php, html, if-statement, conditional-statements

I need to display one of two div s -- one if file uploaded is image,
another for pdf. I dont know how to program if else statement in html.
Heres my code (but it just prints {% if on the screen):

html:

```
{% if "<?php echo $rows['img']; ?>" != "upload/images/1.pdf" %}

<div id="myDiv" class="img-wrapper">
</div>

{% else %}

<div id="myPdfDiv" class="pdf-image">
</div>

{% endif %}
```

Comment: sorry what is `{%` ? are you using some client side framework or is some kind of template like Blade?

Comment: if found this {% if example on inet, saying it will work for html. No I need plain html, no framework

Comment: how to implement 2 div s?

Comment: HTML can't do if/else. What you see here is a server side template. It needs to be processed by something (php?).

Answer (score 1):

Use you any templating framework? What is {%%} block content? Is this Twig?

You should this if you don't use template system (and this file extension to be .php doesn't .html):

```
<?php if($rows['img'] != "upload/images/1.pdf"){ ?>
<div id="myDiv" class="img-wrapper"></div>
<?php }else{ ?>
<div id="myPdfDiv" class="pdf-image"></div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Seems like your code doesnt work properly. when i open a web page i see 2 divs simultaneously

Comment: Do you send the screenshot about the error? I interest how to look it.

Comment: I dont know how to attach images here

Comment: my code shows image and pdf only if i place the following 2 lines with <script> after if div 1 else div 2. it shows nothing if i write these <script> in <head> of html         <script src="view_topic.js" id="view_topic" data-url="<?php echo $rows['img']; ?>"></script>
   <script src="view_pdf.js" id="view_pdf" data-url="<?php echo $rows['img']; ?>"></script>

Comment: if i remove if div 1 else div 2 block still i see the pdf (btw it displays a png if the file is png, not pdf). but in this case not two div s are displayed but only one for pdf. js file contains the following line:     $("body").append(`<p><embed src='${imgUrl}' + type='application/pdf', width='40%', height='40%', class='pdf_image'></p>`);

Answer (score 0):

Your first line is troublesome. This would work:

{% if my_flag != 0 %}

Flag is not zero

{% else %}

Flag is zero

{% endif %}